# About X-content-type-options

Tags: http-headers, x-content-type-options

I am developing a website and lastly I checked for vulnerabilities I found about X CONTENT TYPE in my website. I took mozilla developers as refrence and I knew this can be removed by using code
     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Anyone could suggest me where ro use it?